# How can I have ArcGIS not automatically add raster clip output from Python window to the current map

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, raster, geoprocessing, arcpy

I have a collection of rasters that I'm writing code to automate clipping based on a user defined shapefile. I am currently doing this in the Python window using the following as the main processing function:

```
arcpy.Clip_management( inputRasterFilename, "#", outputRasterFilename, "shapefile" )
```

Basically I want to read the raster, clip it, and have it saved to outputRasterFilename for later use.

This is exactly what happens except that ArcGIS also adds the result of clip operation to the current map that I have open. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: This [post on ESRI's forums asks](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17786-AddOutputsToMap) the equivalent question of a way to do this programmatically using Python. The OP seems to indicate this was available in 9.3 via arcgisscripting and now he wants to do it in 10.0 via arcpy.

Comment: This [post on ESRI's  forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/20040-adding-processed-shapefiles-to-ArcMap-automatically) gives a good workaround: always have the dialog disable and use the AddLayer function in the arcpy.mapping module to add outputs as needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change this setting in the MXD by clicking Geoprocessing|Geoprocessing Options and unclicking "Add results of geoprocessing operations to the display".

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to set this programmatically?

Comment: I know how to set it in .NET, but I don't know Python well enough yet for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 14):

With ArcGIS 10.1 it is possible to disable add output to the application display with arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000004s000000

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddOutputsToMap_Property/002n0000012r000000/) is ESRI's documentation for doing it in .NET:

Comment: -1: This has nothing to do with what the OP requested since they're using arcpy. They don't have access to the IGeoProcessor namespace (or any other .Net namespace, for that matter). Furthermore, it's not really "documentation for doing it", it's a link to a method that allows or disallows adding outputs within ArcObjects.